# How is this question opinion based?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

[Besides fruits and milk, what other things in nature are "intended" to be eaten?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/51258/besides-fruits-and-milk-what-other-things-in-nature-are-intended-to-be-eaten)

I understand that it initially could stir up some emotions regarding the use of language and lack of context, but after the fourth revision and some clarifications, it got put on-hold as opinion based.

How is this question opinion based?

Comment: I don't think it is really opinion based. Perhaps if you can clarify what constitutes "being eaten" then the question can become more precise. For example, would you consider the egg yolk as something that is eaten by the embryo?

Comment: @WYSIWYG I'm not very involved in the question, I just found it interesting and didn't understand why it was put on hold.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I assumed you were the one who asked the question.

Comment: @WYSIWYG No worries, but so you are suggesting that it's more of a "unclear what you're asking", rather than "primarily opinion based answers"?

Comment: Perhaps yes but there is no point in reopening the post and closing again as unclear. I am not sure if it really needs to be closed. I think that certain clarifications can be provided which would improve the question. Overall, I can't see the OP's rationale behind this question.

Comment: @WYSIWYG I see your point about re-labeling the question. I'm interested in what you mean about the rationale behind the question. Is it just a personal observation, or do you mean that a lack of clear rationale behind a question can be a valid reason for closing it?

Comment: That was just a comment. If the OP provides some rationale then it may also help in making the question a bit more precise. I didn't say that it deserves to be closed.

Comment: @WYSIWYG Ok, then I understand. Thank you.